# Retrieve multiple users info from firebase auth using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication to store users. I have two types of users: Manager and Employee. I am storing the manager's UID in Firestore employee along with the employee's UID. The structure is shown below.

**Firestore structure**

> ```
> Company
> |
> > Document's ID
>               |
>               > mng_uid: Manager's UID
>               > emp_uid: Employee's UID
> ```

Now I want to perform a query like "Retrieve employees' info which is under the specific manager." To do that I tried to run the below code.

```
module.exports = {
    get_users: async (mng_uid, emp_uid) => {
        return await db.collection("Company").where("manager_uid", "==", mng_uid).get().then(snaps => {
            if (!snaps.empty) {
                let resp = {};
                let i = 0;
                snaps.forEach(async (snap) => {
                    resp[i] = await admin.auth().getUser(emp_uid).then(userRecord => {
                        return userRecord;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        return err;
                    });
                    i++;
                });
                return resp;
            }
            else return "Oops! Not found.";
        }).catch(() => {
            return "Error in retrieving employees.";
        });
    }
}
```

Above code returns `{}`. I tried to debug by returning data from specific lines. I got to know that the issue is in retrieving the user's info using firebase auth function which I used in `forEach` loop. But it is not returning any error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several points to be corrected in your code:

- You use `async/await` with `then()` which is not recommended. Only use one of these approaches.
- If I understand correctly your goal ("Retrieve employees' info which is under the specific manager"), you do not need to pass a `emp_uid` parameter to your function, but for each `snap` you need to read the value of the `emp_uid` field with `snap.data().emp_uid`
- Finally, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to execute all the asynchronous `getUser()` method calls in parallel.

So the following should do the trick:

```
  module.exports = {
    get_users: async (mng_uid) => {
      try {
        const snaps = await db
          .collection('Company')
          .where('manager_uid', '==', mng_uid)
          .get();

        if (!snaps.empty) {
          const promises = [];
          snaps.forEach(snap => {
            promises.push(admin.auth().getUser(snap.data().emp_uid));
          });

          return Promise.all(promises);  //This will return an Array of UserRecords

        } else return 'Oops! Not found.';
      } catch (error) {
        //...
      }
    },
  };
```

Comment: Is there any way to fetch only the ```displayName``` field instead of fetching the whole user object from firebase auth?

Comment: No, the `getUser()ˋ method returns an entire ´UserRecord´.